# Angular dropdown div within JSON table

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:query | orderBy:sortField:reverse">
<td><b>{{emp.ranking}}</b></td>
<td>{{emp.name}}</td>
<td>{{emp.degree}}</td>
<td>{{emp.years}}</td>
<td>{{emp.field}}</td>
<td>{{emp.job}}</td>
</tr>
```

I am pulling the data above from a JSON file using `$htttp.get` and would like to know if for each individual table cell/row I can attach a different div that slides down when the cell or row is selected using Angular.

Comment: What do you mean slides down? You could have a hidden div in each cell and a flag driven by ng-click to enable.

Comment: Yes that is what I am going for it doesn't necessarily have to "slide down."

Comment: Can multiple be opened at once? That determines where you put the flag.

Comment: Yes that would work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
<td ng-click="emp.showJobDetails = !emp.showJobDetails;">
  {{emp.job}}
  <div ng-if="emp.showJobDetails">Some hidden content</div>
</td>
```